# Drupal - shows content after refresh

Tags: php, drupal

Have issue with clients site. when showing content first time  -it shows blank page.
After refresh - we have all content.

Can anybody help?

Comment: This would be a great time to post an example, or a jsFiddle. Or something.

Comment: try disabling the cache completely.

Comment: i try this ... no affect. Maybe problem is in RaskSpace hosting ... tehre is some kind of caching of files operations, as i understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not a real solution
but try to add this

```
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

at the top of node.tpl.php in your theme files...if its working we can move to the second step..

Comment: am not 100% sure if this works, but matter - seems was in cloud-hosting & cache system of this drupal.